# k-CFA analysis for Java

Tags: java, static-analysis

I have been searching for quite a time, trying to find an implementation of k-CFA analysis for OOP languages, particulary Java. Does someone know if there is one available online?

Comment: [A simple implementation of k-CFA](https://code.google.com/p/streme/source/browse/streme/src/streme/lang/ast/analysis/kcfa/Kcfa.java)

Comment: Isn't that an implementation for Scheme?

Comment: I just posted the link as an additional resource for your research, also the liked homepage of [Matt Might](http://matt.might.net/) might help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might try to take a look at Soot, an analysis environment for Java, and in particular the projects SPARK and Paddle (see e.g. http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/paddle/), which are libraries using Soot to perform points-to-analyses. At least Paddle seems to have options to use k-CFA context-sensitive analyses, which is described in the Soot Survival guide: http://www.brics.dk/SootGuide/sootsurvivorsguide.pdf.